# Configuration error when using postfix with postgrey

Tags: postfix

I have installed postgrey and added the following to main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
```

Now my postfix does not relay any mails anymore. It provides following messages:

```
May 18 18:54:43 r2 postfix/smtpd[3351]: connect from mx02.posteo.de[89.146.194.165]
May 18 18:54:43 r2 postfix/smtpd[3351]: warning: premature end-of-input on 127.0.0.1:10023 while reading input attribute name
May 18 18:54:44 r2 postfix/smtpd[3351]: warning: premature end-of-input on 127.0.0.1:10023 while reading input attribute name
May 18 18:54:44 r2 postfix/smtpd[3351]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:10023: Success
May 18 18:54:44 r2 postfix/smtpd[3351]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx02.posteo.de[89.146.194.165]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<wi@koczewski.de> to=<wi@koczewski.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx02.posteo.de>
May 18 18:54:44 r2 postfix/smtpd[3351]: disconnect from mx02.posteo.de[89.146.194.165]
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Or how to find out what "Server configuration problem" I have?

Answer (score 0):

Commas are missing after each of the rules, should be:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:1002
```